# How do you export a blender file as an .avi file in Blender 2.74?

Tags: video

I am working on a video file in Blender. I have saved it as a .blend file already, but I want to save it as an .avi file.

How do I do this? I have watched multiple tutorials and have no idea what to do. I am using Blender 2.74.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're working on a video edit in the VSE, correct? And you just need to export your video as an AVI file?

Answer (score 0):

In order to export your video edit to a new AVI file, you need to:

1. Set your **Render Settings to a movie format that supports AVI**
2. Click the **Render Animation button**.

As long as you have the Sequence checkbox selected in the Post Processing panel, it should render out your video edit to a new video file.

There are a number of Movie formats that also support the AVI encoding format.

They include:

- AVI JPEG
- AVI Raw
- H.264 (with AVI format selected)
- MPEG (with AVI format selected)
- Xvid (with AVI format selected)

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't setting the Audio Codec to `None` result in a **mute** video?