# After render when click Play Rendered Animation, it says 'file not found." What do I do to fix that?

Tags: rendering

So, I am new to blender. I downloaded a Youtube intro from a video and put it into blender, changed the name, and put the thing that makes it save when it is done. I never closed it and when it was done, it didn't save so i saved it myself but I can't figure out how to save it as a AVI Raw file that way. So then I just saved it as a blender file and went to the file and clicked Play Rendered Animation and it said "File Blah Blah.avi not found" or something like that. I clicked play at the bottom and you can here the sound but the video is just a grey square with a plus in it, like a window. What do I do to fix this?

Comment: When rendering animation we usually do so in sequence. Meaning rendering images one by one and save them as Jpegs or other image format. That's because it's a better way of rendering animation for post production work... like color correction and adding special effects. You will want the check if you have specified the local drive location where then renderer should output those frame to. And the file you downloaded is rendering to an AVI or a sequence.

Comment: See if [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/32313/2217) or [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15145/2217) helps.

Comment: @hawkenfox Thanks! I did check where I saved it and did make sure it was a AVI Raw. Does it matter if it is AVI or AVI Raw?

Comment: @David Thank you! The first answer helped a little!